# Screens go black, return with hit of Windows key

Tags: windows-7, display, multiple-monitors

So I have a dual-monitor setup and every once in awhile (pretty random amounts of time), both of my monitors will go black. I can't fully characterize this at the moment because I haven't used my desktop in awhile so it hasn't happened for some time and now that I'm back at it, I forgot to pay attention. If I remember correctly, all sound and other functions are still operating correctly while the screen goes black. I have an RGB keyboard and mouse and both still cycle through colors. I used to try and hit a whole bunch of keys on my keyboard and nothing would work. I also, powered my monitors off and back on again and fully unplugged them from the computer. Just today, it happened again and I just happened to hit the Windows key because I was trying to do a restart using hotkeys since I couldn't see the screen and the screens both instantly returned. I am under the assumption that this is a video card issue since it's the screens going out but I'm not really sure. Please let me know if you have any ideas of possibilities causing this or troubleshooting steps.

Comment: is your video card particularly underspecced or quite old? do you have any idea what temp its running at?

Comment: My video card is a Gigabyte Windforce GTX 960 4GB card so a pretty decent card. It is currently running at 33 degrees Celsius and I haven't seen it go above 40 so it doesn't really run that hot either. I have a full tower case with as many fans installed as I can so that I don't have to worry about cooling issues

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your video card isn't getting enough signal in order to render the screen.  I would try a lower resolution to see if that helps.  You also should make sure you are on 60Hz.  Sometimes when adding a monitor my computer would go to 59Hz instead.  This might affect the screen rendering.  Try plugging in a different monitor to it.  Something else to consider might be to go to one monitor.  I know with my laptop if I do 2 monitors with one laptop, this affected the rendering of the flatscreen I had.  Once I went down to just the flatscreen, and not the laptop monitor the system would render the one screen fine.  Just some ideas.